# Is there a free online repository where I can download X-ray diffraction (XRD) data?

Tags: spectroscopy, databases, x-ray-diffraction

It's as the title of the question states. To be specific, I'm wondering if there are any free online repositories where I can download (.csv or .txt. or .xsl) files for x-ray diffraction (XRD) data.

Comment: +1 but I had to change the title to match your question's body. You've probably seen this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1/5. Also I think FTIR/UV-vis/etc. data is very different from XRD and warrants a separate question of its own. As for FTIR data, you simply want the energy transitions in a .txt file?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a site or database (if such a thing exists) where I could get data or .txt files of (absorbance/transmittance vs. wavenumber) for different solutions or materials.

Comment: How about [HITRAN](https://hitran.org/data-index/)?

Comment: @NikeDattani Oh swell, thanks!

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with XRD though, which is why I suggested a separate question about spectroscopic databases.

Answer (score 6):

The [Crystallography Open Database](http://crystallography.net/cod/index.php) is a good database of experimental crystal structures, take a look at their .hkl files which contain [structure factors](https://www.iucr.org/education/pamphlets/3/full-text).

The [Materials Project](https://materialsproject.org), a computational database, also calculations X-ray diffraction patterns and absorption patterns (disclosure, I'm on the Materials Project staff).

You can also generate your own once you have a crystal structure, many tools exist to generate a diffraction pattern, for example [pymatgen](https://pymatgen.org) using the [`XRDCalculator`](https://pymatgen.org/pymatgen.analysis.diffraction.xrd.html), though these will need to be artificially broadened if you want something that looks like an experimental pattern.

Answer (score 4):

For x-ray diffraction and Raman spectroscopy data of minerals, you may try https://rruff.info/

According to their site, "The RRUFF™ Project is creating a complete set of high quality spectral data from well characterized minerals and is developing the technology to share this information with the world. Our collected data provides a standard for mineralogists, geoscientists, gemologists and the general public for the identification of minerals both on earth and for planetary exploration."